# Adding an Image Button to Layout - Unfortunately app has stopped error

Tags: android, android-intent, runtime

I am new to android programming and trying to add image button to the layout, however when i launch the application, it shows me the message "Unfortunately app has stopped", I tried the solutions that were given here, but none of them seems to work. Please see to it and let me know where the problem is and how to rectify it.
Thanks a lot for your time

Here is the logcat file

```
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): Process: com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux, PID: 3856
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux/com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     ... 9 more
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     ... 25 more
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/button1.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2099)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:139)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     ... 27 more
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag Selector
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2095)
10-18 08:21:35.667: E/AndroidRuntime(3856):     ... 31 more
```

Here is the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the button1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button1_pressed" />

  <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button1_focused" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_normal" />    


</Selector>
```

Here is the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux.MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button1"
        android:paddingTop="5px">
        </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dkdsoft.dkdsoftux"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Exception(`Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/button1.xml`), it cannot find the `button1.xml` file. Made sure its in `res/drawable` folder of you project. If its present, refresh the project, clean it and re-build.

Comment: Thanks , but button1.xml file is there , i can compile and run the program, but can't launch the application

Comment: Try creating it again outside the project somewhere. Then copy it to the project. Don;t use xml creator of IDE. What happens then?